# Having issues with gamesharing on PS4

Tags: ps4

I've been game sharing Destiny 2 and PS Plus with a friend of mine and recently he decided to buy the Forsaken DLC on his account (Destiny 2 and PS Plus were purchased on my account).

So I logged into his account and set my PS4 as primary so I could obtain the DLC but for some reason he lost all access to my PS Plus subscription but still has access to the games hes downloaded off my account. He only had access to my PS Plus subscription if I login to his account and deactivate my PS4, but then I lose the ability to play the Forsaken DLC.

Is there a way for me to have access to the Forsaken DLC and for him to have access to my games and PS Plus at the same time or does he have to buy PS Plus as well?